# How to change what Heroku's own loggers log

Tags: logging, heroku

Is it possible to change Heroku's log format in any way? 
For example remove the IP logging from it?

Just to be clear, I'm taking about the logs Heroku itself generates, not those generated by the app.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: GDPR, we need to filter IP addresses out.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have considered IP addresses personal data but apparently [GDPR does](https://eugdprcompliant.com/personal-data/). I wonder what "in some cases" means, though.

Comment: If you mean, `in some cases you may track IP addresses`, then in our case were tracking IPs for any access to the admin paths and any access to payment paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible directly from heroku's logs.

However, Heroku will only keep the last 1500 log lines for any app.
You can setup a [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) to retain more logs (this is what log retention tools like LogEntries do).
Then, as you get the data and store it, you can decide what you desire to keep and to delete.

Comment: Do Heroku's logs get mixed in with your own (thus saved to your log services like paper-trail) or does it only display them in the same stream?

Comment: There's a single stream which includes both the app logs as well as the platform ones.

Comment: hmmm do you know a way to filter them out?

Comment: It has to happen within the log drain. There is no way to do that at the heroku level.